# NO PUEDO CONECTAR UN SERVIDOR TCP/IP HECHO EN PYTHON CON UN PLC FX3U POR MEDIO DEL MODULO FX3U-ENET DE MITSUBISHI

Tags: python, servidor, tcpip

buen día!
Estoy realizando un servidor tcp/ip para recibir información en mi laptop con python, intento conectarme a un PLC misubishi modelo fx3u con un modulo de ethernet fx3u-ENET, enviare programa del servidor en python, y de la configuración del plc hecho en gxworks 2, mi duda es:

1.- saber si mi servidor esta bien hecho para comunicarme con medios externos,

2.- ¿alguien a realizado este tipo de conexión en plc mitsubishi? y

3.- Como puedo comprobar la conexion de mi plc con la pc desde hercules.

nota: el código ejecuta una interfaz con tkinter en donde solo se selecciona el puerto, la dirección IP la obtengo con socket.gethostname() (quisiera verificar si lo hice correctamente); el PLC es cliente. Y tengo desactivado el firewall.introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

programa:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
from tkinter import *


# Inicializar ventana --------------------------------------------------------------------------
ventana = Tk()


def segundo_plano():
    t = threading.Thread(target=conexion)
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()


def conexion():
    ipport = port1.get()
    # Create a TCP/IP socket
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    # Bind the socket to the address given on the command line
    server_name = socket.gethostname() # host1.get()
    server_address = (server_name, ipport)
    msg1 = 'Iniciando en IP: {} Puerto: {}'.format(*server_address)
    labelmsg.insert(END, msg1)
    print('Iniciando en IP: {} Puerto: {}'.format(*server_address))
    sock.bind(server_address)
    sock.listen(1)

    while True:
        msg2 = 'Esperando por una conexion...'
        labelmsg.insert(END, msg2)
        print('Esperando por una conexion...')
        connection, client_address = sock.accept()
        try:
            msg3 = 'Cliente Conectado!: {}'.format(client_address)
            labelmsg.insert(END, msg3)
            print('Cliente Conectado!: {}'.format(client_address))
            while True:
                data = connection.recv(16)
                if data:
                    labelmsg.insert(END, 'Dato recibido!')
                    print('Recibido: {!r}'.format(data))
                    # connection.sendall(data)
                    # save_data()
                    # return data
                else:
                    break
        finally:
            connection.close()


# host1 = StringVar()
port1 = IntVar()
ventana.title("Servidor tcp/ip")
ventana.geometry("450x400")
ventana.resizable(0, 0)
# labelHost = Label(ventana, text="Host:").place(x=10, y=10)
#text1 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=host1).place(x=45, y=10)
labelPort = Label(ventana, text="Port:").place(x=185, y=10)
text2 = Entry(ventana, textvariable=port1).place(x=218, y=10)
labelmsg = Listbox(ventana, height=10, width=59)
labelmsg.place(x=45, y=60)
checkone = Button(ventana, text="Conectar", command=segundo_plano).place(x=360, y=10)
ventana.mainloop()
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sys.exit()
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: no se pudieron agregar las imagenes

Comment: ahora ya se visualizan las imágenes :D Recuerda visitar https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour y aquí algunas recomendaciones: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822 Bienvenido a SOes :D